# Can the F8 key be used in both javascript and windowForm in my application?

Tags: javascript, keydown, windows

I have a windows application that runs if we press <kbd>F8</kbd> key.

Also i have a javascript code that fires an event in browser when pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> key.

My problem is when we press <kbd>F8</kbd> only the windows application captures it and Browser doesn't understand the <kbd>F8</kbd> key has been pressed.

What should i do to run both my app and browser with pressing the key?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent browser's default action add `return false;`.

Prevent action with all keys :

```
window.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    //...

    return false;
};
```

Prevent action only with F8 :

```
window.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    //...

    if (evt.keyCode == 119) //F8
        return false;
};
```

*(This solution depends of application's keyevent method).*

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I am on the right line with this - you have no code to demonstrate what may be wrong.
The js code checking for the keypress can only do so for the browser - not the complete desktop.
Therefore, when the browser has focus, the js code will capture it (and the desktop application will not), and vice versa.
If you wanted to press Ctrl+S to save a change in Notepad, you wouldn't expect it to save data in all open Notepads, it would only save for the one that has focus.